# Visibility modifier affects Object property visibility

Tags: kotlin

I have an example code below:

```
class C {

    private val obj = object {
        val x: String = "x"
    }

    fun printX() {
        println(obj.x)
    }

}
```

If I remove `private` modifier from `obj`, then `x` will become unresolved in `printX` function. Can anybody explain me the "compiler's logic" behind this? Thank you.

Comment: This is purely a design decision to let you keep local access to anonymous classes. Exposing them publicly would make no sense in a strong typed language, for that purpose you have to define an explicit class.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but this does not answer my question. Why removing private modifier makes x inaccessible in printX()? printX() is LOCAL. obj is val, i.e. immutable.